# Фильтрация GridView YiI2

Tags: php, yii2, filter

Нужна подсказка. Осваиваю Yii2 и тут возникла проблема.
Есть таблица USER и GridView c данными из этой таблицы - фильтрация работает.
И есть таблица SEND и GridView c данными из этой таблицы - тут он никак не выполняет фильтрацию. Код брался из класса User и SearchUser.

КОНТРОЛЛЕР

```
public function actionAllsend(){

    if(isAdmin()){
        $searchModel = new SendSearch();
        //Получим записи по конкретному пользователю
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        return $this->render('allsend', [
          'searchModel' => $searchModel,
          'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
    else{
      return $this->redirect(['site/index']);
    }
}
```

МОДЕЛЬ

```
public function search($params, $userName = null)
    {
        $this->load($params);

       // Получим все записи либо записи по конкретному пользователю
        if($userName == null){
            $query = Send::find();
             // grid filtering conditions
            $query->andFilterWhere([
                'id' => $this->id,

        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user_id', $this->user_id])
              ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'type', $this->type])
              ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'date', $this->date])
              ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'status', $this->status]);

        }
        else{
            $query = Send::find();

            $query->andFilterWhere([
                'user_id' => $userName,
            ]);
        }

//                    echo $query;


        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                 'forcePageParam' => false,
                 'pageSizeParam' => false,
                'pageSize' => 20
            ]
        ]);


        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

ВЬЮХА

```
<div class="admin-all-send">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            //['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            ['attribute'=>'id', "label"=>'Уникальный номер рассылки'],
            ['attribute'=>'date', "label"=>'Дата транзакции'],
            ['attribute'=>'user_id', 'label'=>'Чья рассылка'],
            ['attribute'=>'type', 'label'=>'Тип  рассылки'],
            ['attribute'=>'status', "label" => "Статус рассылки"],
            ['attribute'=>'price', 'label'=>'Цена рассылки'],

           ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
             'template' => '{view}  {delete}',   
            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел проблему. Косяк в модели был.
Так работате:

```
public function search($params, $userName = null)
    {
        $this->load($params);

       // Получим все записи либо записи по конкретному пользователю
        if($userName == null){
            $query = Send::find();
             // grid filtering conditions
            $query->andFilterWhere([
                'id' => $this->id,

             ]);

        }
        else{
            $query = Send::find();

            $query->andFilterWhere([
                'user_id' => $userName,
            ]);
        }

         $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user_id', $this->user_id])
              ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'type', $this->type])
              ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'date', $this->date])
              ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'status', $this->status]);
//                    echo $query;


        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                 'forcePageParam' => false,
                 'pageSizeParam' => false,
                'pageSize' => 20
            ]
        ]);


        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```